# How to handle exceptions in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, servlet-filters

I am working in a spring mvc based project and have developed a `ExceptionResolver` by extending `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` to redirect to error page depending on the exception type. It is working for exception raised at facade, service, DAO layer.

But it doesn't work for any exceptions raised in Servlet filter. What changes should be made for that?

Below is my handlerExceptionResolver

```
public ModelAndView doResolveException(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object obj,
        final Exception exception){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = super.doResolveException(request, response, obj, exception);

    modelAndView = Objects.nonNull(modelAndView) ? modelAndView : new ModelAndView();
    final String url = Config.getParameter(EXCEPTION_HANDLER_URL);

    modelAndView.setViewName(url);
    final FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
    outputFlashMap.put(ERROR_DETAILS, exception);

    if (exception instanceof BusinessExecutionException)
    {
        return handleBusinessExecutionExceptionMethod((BusinessExecutionException) exception, outputFlashMap, modelAndView);

    }
    else if (exception instanceof IntegrationExecutionException)
    {
        return handleIntegrationExecutionExceptionMethod((IntegrationExecutionException) exception, outputFlashMap,
                modelAndView);
    }
    else if (exception instanceof DataAccessObjectExecutionException)
    {
        return handleDAOExecutionExceptionMethod((DataAccessObjectExecutionException) exception, outputFlashMap, modelAndView);
    }

    return handleMiscException(exception, outputFlashMap, modelAndView);

}
```

Comment: Couldn't tell you what changes would need to be made if you don't provide what you have now.

Comment: Take a look into this http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring exception handler:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
It is convenient - you can "catch" exception regarding type and HTTP status.